# pycharm export complete key map file as xml?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to programmatically create a keymap for pycharm. I have an ergonomic keyboard for which the function keys are very awkward to hit. I'd like to map everything with a function key to something with a prefix, so for example, (I'm on mac os/x)

```
Command + Alt + F7
```

will go to

```
Alt + J
Command + Alt + 7
```

That is I'll use Alt+J as the gateway into my remaps for function keys.

I can do this on an action by action basis, and I've found a xml file at

```
~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm<xx>/keymaps/
```

but it seems to only have my new keymappings. It would be great if I could export an xml file with all the keymappings, and then create my alternative mapping from it. Anyone know how to get a hold of such a complete xml file of the standard keymap?